# How do I initialize DataTables.js' load function AFTER creating the table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am creating a table with ajax. The table displays properly, and is valid html, but I can't initialize DataTables correctly.

I have this html code:

```
<table class="dat">
```

And in my ajax:

```
complete: $('.dat').DataTable(),
```

The table is formatted according to DataTables.js' table guidelines:

```
<table class="dat">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Logo</th>
            <th>Food Name</th>
            <th>Stuff</th>
            <th>Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Image</td>
            <td>Stuff here</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Code</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And part of the jquery AJAX:

```
success: function (z) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(z.d);

    var table = '<table class="dat">';
    table += "  <thead>";
    table += "      <tr>;"
    table += "          <th>Logo</th>";
    table += "          <th>Food Name</th>";
    table += "          <th>Stuff</th>";
    table += "          <th>Code</th>";
    table += "     </tr>";
    table += " </thead>";

    $.each(json, function (i, obj) {
        //console.log(obj);
        table += "  <tbody>";
        table += "      <tr>";
        table += "          <td> Image (" + obj.Logo + ")</td>";
        table += "          <td>" + obj.FoodName + "</td>";

        table += "          <td>";
        $.each(obj.Text, function (j, t) {
            table += t + "; ";
        });
        table += "          </td>"; // Stuff

        table += "          <td>" + obj.Code + "</td>";
        table += "      </tr>";
    });
    table += "  </tbody>";
    table += "</table>";
    $('.search_results').append(table);
    $('.dat').DataTable();
},
```

The html is showing up correctly without any formatting issues, and there are also no errors. The only thing I can do is use the search feature, and it doesn't clear the irrelevant content. Is DataTable() being called before the append feature? That's what I suspected, but the search feature works almost perfectly.

If so, how do I call it after the table is done being loaded? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try first removing any prior listeners and such that DataTable may have already attached to the table (especially since you're identifying it via a Class, rather than an ID).  Then, initialize the table.

So, replace this...

```
$('.dat').DataTable();
```

With this...

```
$('.dat').DataTable().destroy();
$('.dat').DataTable();
```

Comment: It turns out I also forgot to add **class="display"** I've changed this, and changed "dat" to an ID instead of a class. More stuff gets initialized (formatting), but it still doesn't work with this method. I am not calling DataTable() until after the table is created.

Comment: Curiously, I am getting a large block of text which isn't produced by my code at all: "

        ;          ". This semicolon with a lot of spaces appears right before the table creation.

Comment: Aha! There's an error in your JS. Here... `table += " <tr>;"` That's likely causing numerous issues (and would almost certainly break the DOM, causing DataTable to not function quite right).

Comment: Oh wow... thanks to Visual Studio for autocompleting that for me. Haha! I fixed that, but it still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm... I missed something earlier in your original question.  Remove `complete: $('.dat').DataTable()` and see if that helps. If that's in there, and also in the Success callback, then it would be calling the initialize function twice, which may do odd things.

Comment: Yeah, I said I replaced it. My bad, I should've been more clear. I removed the complete: code, and did as you said, and it still doesn't work correctly. I do have a lot of semicolons in my "Stuff" field. ".dat" is now "#dat," by the way.